# Logarithm involving the floor function

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, logarithms

It is well known that

$\log_c(c^ac^b) = \log_c(c^a) + \log_c(c^b) = a+b$

where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}^+$. But how does one solve the equation involving a floor function:

$\log_c(\lfloor c^ac^b \rfloor) = ?$

Is there a formula for such a case, or even a formula for expanding $\lfloor c^ac^b \rfloor$, without the simplification to $\lfloor c^{a+b} \rfloor$?

Comment: not sure of any properties, but you can bound it: $$ \log_c(c^ac^b - 1) < \log_c(\lfloor c^ac^b \rfloor) \le a + b $$ however, I don't think this is quite useful due to the LHS, so just a comment.

Comment: @Dando18 Post the answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of a more simplified closed form of $\log_c \left( \lfloor c^a c^b \rfloor \right)$, apart from $\log_c\left(\lfloor c^{a+b} \rfloor\right)$. However, one can use upper and lower bounds,

$$ \log_c \left( c^a c^b - 1 \right) < \log_c \left(\lfloor c^a c^b \rfloor\right) \le a+b .$$

Which is already fairly tight for small values of $a$ and $b$ and large values of $c$. See [this plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3ffzzqgqqy) of $g(x)=\log_x\left( \lfloor x^ax^b \rfloor\right)$, $f(x)=\log_x\left( x^ax^b - 1 \right)$, and $h(x)=a+b$. Also shown below for $a=b=1$,

[image: plot images]